# Android: A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfffffffc in tid 17413 (Loader:Manifest)

Tags: exoplayer

I have used ExoPlayer-V2. We are playing the eHLS online streaming directly into the player.

I am getting below error every time whenever clicking on video playback.

Error:

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfffffffc in tid 17413 (Loader:Manifest)

That's error does not come every time and some of latest device working well without any issues.

Comment: Also I am facing same issue